# How to import a .sql file to sqlite via nodejs exec

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I am using a sqlite3 database in my nodejs/express application.  I would like to import a .sql file to sqlite when I start up the express server.  Since there doesn't appear to be a way to import with the node-sqlite3 package, I'm trying to do it with the exec function.

Both of these commands work when I run them from the command line:

cat db.sql | sqlite3 mydb.db
sqlite3 mydb.db < db.sql

However, when I try to run either of these commands via the nodejs exec function, the mydb.db file is created, but it is empty.  Here is my code:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

child = exec('cat db.sql | sqlite3 mydb.db',
    function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
        console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
        if (error !== null) {
            console.log('exec error: ' + error);
        }
);
```

When I start my express server I get no output:
    Express server listening on ip:localhost port:3000
    stdout:
    stderr:

The db file is created, but with a file size of 0.  When I open it with sqlite, there are no tables in mydb.db

I tried both ways as shown above and neither of them work.  I also tried using spawn and didn't have any success with that, either.  How can I import a sql file to a new db within nodejs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe `|` is a shell tool for chaining commands. In Node you need to separate your commands and redirect first output to next input.

```
var fs = require("fs")
, spawn = require("child_process").spawn
, child = spawn("sqlite3", ["mydb.db"])

fs.createReadStream("./db.sql").pipe(child.stdin)
```